# Specific Friend Function Specialization

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class like follows:

```
namespace n
{
    template<class integral>
    class ex
    {
    public:
        friend auto ::operator +(integral i,
                                 ex const & e)
        {
            return i + e.i;
        }
        int i;
    }
}
```

This code does not work because `operator +` is not in the global namespace.

What can be done to allow this inline, immediate definition?
I'd like to do this without declaring a global templated `operator +` and then declaring the friend as a seperate templated function?

```
namespace n
{
    template<class integral>
    class ex
    {
    public:
        template<class operator_integral> // redundant
        friend auto ::operator +(operator_integral i,
                                 ex<operator_integral> const & e); // longer
        //{
        //  return i + e.i; // can no longer define here
        //}
        int i;
    }
}

template<class operator_integral> // AGAIN
auto operator +(operator_integral i,
                ex<operator_integral> const & e); // AGAIN AGAIN
{
    return i + e.i; // definition is now far away
}
```

Comment: why you need `operator +` in global namespace?

Comment: @appleapple You can't use an operator in a namespace unless you are in that namespace or declare a `using namespace` or something similar.

Comment: well, I don't really understand what you want, please add use case code.

Comment: re your comment: [it does work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O5nbFZvlqHFbj9L4) without being in global namespace (ADL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, because of [Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) it will work fine if you just drop the scope operator from the friend declaration:

```
namespace n
{
    template<class integral>
    class ex
    {
    public:
        // Note lack of scope operator in declaration
        friend auto operator +(integral i,
                               ex const & e)
        {
            return i + e.i;
        }
        int i;
    }
}
```

Can be used as e.g.:

```
n::ex<int> x;
auto r = 12 + x;
```

No `using` directive needed.

Comment: Ahh! Forgot about ADL. Works! This is what I get for debugging code before finishing it.